# Filter dataframe based on corresponding rows in another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

would like to create df3 where the url would come from df1 and the traffic value from corresponding rows in df2.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd 


data = [['http://url1.com'], ['http://url3.com']]
data_2 = [[{'url':'http://url1.com', 'traffic':100}], [{'url':'http://url2.com', 'traffic':200}], [{'url':'http://url3.com', 'traffic':300}]] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['url'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_2, columns=['url', 'traffic'])


df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='url')
```

Expected output:

```
                             url traffic
0                 http://url1.com  100
1                 http://url3.com  300
```

Current output:

```
ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

Comment: The problem is with creation of `df2`. You could use `df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dct for row in data_2 for dct in row])`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yes it works. Could you make any short explanation for this?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem thanks! I have one  problem here though. When data dataframe has https but data_2 http adresses it does not match. I guess a simple search and replace would work right? I am wondering why this is not working: df1.replace(to_replace = 'https', value='http')

Comment: @Michal, try `df1.replace(to_replace = 'https', value='http', regex=True)`

Comment: @Corralien hmm strange, now it works. I dont know what I did wrong previously. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding https and http, you need to make sure you overwrite the `dataframe`:

```py
import pandas as pd 

data = [['https://url1.com'], ['https://url3.com']]
data_2 = [[{'url':'http://url1.com', 'traffic':100}], [{'url':'http://url2.com', 'traffic':200}], [{'url':'http://url3.com', 'traffic':300}]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['url'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([row[0] for row in data_2])

df1 = df1.replace(to_replace = 'https', value='http', regex=True)
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='url')
print(df3)
```

```
               url  traffic
0  http://url1.com      100
1  http://url3.com      300
```